# Url Manager is not working In my yii2 applicatoin

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-url-manager

I'm trying to set Url Manager in my yii2 basic template. Below is `.htaccess` file which is locate `mysite.loc/web/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks IndexIgnore

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php RewriteRule . index.php
```

and inside my `web.php` file I've added this code snippet:

```
'urlManager' => [
     'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
     'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
],
```

When I'm trying to enter (For example) `mysite.loc/index.php/site/movies` It comes error like this: `404 not found error nginx`

If anybody knows share me please. What's wrong with my settings???

Comment: Show your virtual host config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read several topics and have found correct answer. There is a difference between apache configuration and nginx configuration on setting urlManager.

If Your server Apache (as Vitaly said above):

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

config/web.php :

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

---

If your server is Nginx:

nginx congfig file (in my case /etc/ngnix/site-enabled/mysite.loc) :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/mysite.loc/web;
    server_name mysite.loc www.mysite.loc;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {            
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

As you can see I have added this snippet of code and nothing more :

```
location / {            
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

config/web.php file is same as Apache server :

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

My config

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

config/web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

Try above and go to url `mysite.loc/site/movies`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vitaly :-) but your answer is correct for apache servers. I'm using nginx server. As you can see in my question I said "it comes error: 404 not found error nginx".